# Resample hourly to daily and group by min, max and mean values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a hourly dataframe, `df`, and i need to create a new dataframe with the `min`, `mean` and `max` values from each day. Here's what i tried to do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(72, 1),
                    columns=["Random"],
                    index=pd.date_range(start="20220101000000", end="20220103230000", freq='H'))

df_min = df.resample('D').min()
df_mean = df.resample('D').mean()
df_max = df.resample('D').max()
```

But not really sure how could group those three dataframes (`df_min`, `df_mean` and `df_max`) into a new single dataframe, `df_new`. This new dataframe should have only one column, something like this:

```
2022-01-01T00:00:00.00 0.002  <- min
2022-01-01T00:00:00.00 0.023  <- mean
2022-01-01T00:00:00.00 0.965  <- max
2022-01-02T00:00:00.00 0.013  <- min
2022-01-02T00:00:00.00 0.053  <- mean
2022-01-02T00:00:00.00 0.825  <- max
2022-01-03T00:00:00.00 0.011  <- min
2022-01-03T00:00:00.00 0.172  <- mean
2022-01-03T00:00:00.00 0.992  <- max
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Resample.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html) with list of functions, then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and remove second level of `MultiIndex` by [`Series.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.droplevel.html):

```
s = df.resample('D')['Random'].agg(['min','mean','max']).stack().droplevel(1)
print (s)
2022-01-01    0.162976
2022-01-01    0.574074
2022-01-01    0.980742
2022-01-02    0.012299
2022-01-02    0.467338
2022-01-02    0.962570
2022-01-03    0.000722
2022-01-03    0.426793
2022-01-03    0.947014
dtype: float64
```